# Problem using rsamples::bootstraps object with ".$" inside purrr::map

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, tidymodels

It's pretty common to use `%>%` operator in conjuction with `.` as a representation of the left-hand-side (LHS) object of `%>%`, for example:

```
library(purrr)
mtcars %>% 
  split(.$cyl) %>%    # as you can see here
  map(~ lm(mpg ~ hp, data = .x))
```

But using `rsample::bootstraps()` function to create a tibble with a bootstrap-list-column, where each element have a dataset, I noticed an error using the `.` pattern describe above that I don´t understand well.

```
library(purrr)
# create a 3 partitions

# inspect how many cyl == 4 are in each partition (ERROR)
rsample::bootstraps(mtcars, times = 3) %>%
map_dbl(.$splits,
        function(x) {
                     cyl = as.data.frame(x)$cyl
                     mean(cyl == 4)
                    })
Error: Index 1 must have length 1, not 4
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

But instead if you store the output of `rsample::bootstraps()` in the `ex` object and then use `map_dbl`, as you can see in the [documentation](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/bootstraps.html), it works properly.

```
library(purrr)
# create 3 partitions
ex <- rsample::bootstraps(mtcars, times = 3)

# inspect how many cyl == 4 are in each partition (WORKS OK)
map_dbl(ex$splits,
        function(x) {
                     cyl = as.data.frame(x)$cyl
                     mean(cyl == 4)
                    })
 [1] 0.50000 0.28125 0.43750
```

Any idea to understand this behavior between procedures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not really specific to `rsample`. This is just how the `%>%` from `magrittr` works. Consider

```
mtcars %>% 
  mean(.$carb)
```

This also results in an error. Because what it's basically calling is

```
mean(mtcars, mtcars$carb)
```

By default the pipe will always place what you are piping in to the first parameter of the function. You can move it to a different parameter with `.` alone, but since you are not doing that here, you are still getting the entire first object passed to the first parameter of the function along with an additional parameter of `.$samples` but that doesn't match the signature of `map_dbl` that you want to use. This works fine with

```
mtcars %>% 
  split(.$cyl)
```

because `split()` expects the entire data.frame as the first parameter. The correct call to split is

```
split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
```

It's always been the case that if you don't want the first parameter to be filled for you, then you can pipe into a block instead `{}`.

You can do

```
rsample::bootstraps(mtcars, times = 3) %>%
{map_dbl(.$splits,
        function(x) {
                     cyl = as.data.frame(x)$cyl
                     mean(cyl == 4)
                    })}
```

Or you could `pull` the column explicitly

```
rsample::bootstraps(mtcars, times = 3) %>%
  dplyr::pull(splits) %>%
  map_dbl(
        function(x) {
                     cyl = as.data.frame(x)$cyl
                     mean(cyl == 4)
                    })
```